# Android How to implement a change of viewgroup by swipe gesture

Tags: android, transition, fragment, swipe

When using gmail or greader, you can go from one message/news to the next/previous by issuing a swipe gesture.

I wonder how is this behavior best implemented? Is there some built-in view that does that or should I choose the source and destination views and make a transition between them?

Any code example going around for this?

Moreover, let's say I want to swipe from a list to a second list. And when in a tablet I want both lists displayed side by side. Is this a typical fragment usage? Still, how to implement the swipe thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). A brief overview and sample source is available at the Developer's blog entry [Horizontal View Swiping with ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

> I want to swipe from a list to a second list. And when in a tablet I want both lists displayed side by side. Is this a typical fragment usage?

It would be better to use `Fragment` in the above use case.